# 3D Anaglyph Gaming (FIFA10 & Quake3/ioquake3)

Tags: stereo-3d, fifa-10, quake-3

I'm organizing a gaming event, which will have *FIFA 2010* and *Quake 3*. We want the audience to be able to see the action in true 3D, so we're going to make use of anaglyph glasses. For this, we'll be using **ioquake3** and **iZ3D**. My questions here are:

- iZ3D doesn't seem to support Quake 3, though it says it does... or does it?
- Can you spectate on a Quake 3 match using ioquake3?
- What is the best way for adding anaglyph support to Quake3?
- Is anaglyph support even *possible* in Quake4?
- What is the best way to achieve what I want to do?
- Is "spectator mode" possible in **any way** in FIFA 2010?

**It's *okay* if you don't know the answers to all of these questions. Tell me whatever you know. Thanks**

Comment: If this is about a big gaming event that will run multiple times, you might consider going for something newer than anaglyph glasses: [Dolby Digital 3D](http://www.dolby.com/professional/solutions/cinema/3d-digital-cinema.html), [IMAX 3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAX#IMAX_3D), [RealD 3D](http://www.reald.com/), ... If you can't, at least go for the best color-tinted version out there: [Color Code 3D](http://www.colorcode3d.com/)

Comment: Do you mean Quake3, not Quake4?

Comment: TomWij : I'd really like to, but we're limited by our funding. Each pass (for the event) is INR 100 (~USD 2) and we're expecting an audience of about 1000+ people (that's ~2000 USD total, but we can use a maximum of ~500 USD for this). So, are any of the things you mentioned that affordable?

Comment: @Aviral, I'm sorry you couldn't get more answers than this -- would you like me to cast a +200 bounty maybe? :)

Comment: @Aviral Hi. Could you please tell me where the event is being held? This, I would like to attend. (please reply with @Mugen so I get the notification when I log in). Thanks.

Comment: @Mugen I'm sorry, the event in question has already been held (it's in Jamshedpur, India and it's a yearly event) though, we had it without the 3D bit this year (due to planning problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Can you spectate on a Quake 3 match using ioquake3?

I'm afraid you can't, but I can't say for sure. ioQuake3 eventually found one baseq3 server (at 163.36.202.155:27960) but failed to connect to it (it got stuck at Awaiting Challenge). I'm afraid they may be network incompatible by default, then.

---

> #### What is the best way for adding anaglyph support to Quake3?

ioQuake3 [claims](http://ioquake3.org/improvements/) it natively supports anaglyph rendering. You can enable it by using the `r_anaglyphMode 1` cvar.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this site: http://www.stereo3d.com/quake.htm